# JAXB unmarshalling returns null attributes command line

Tags: java, xml, linux, shell, jaxb

JAXB unmarshalling returns null attributes when I run the jar in command line. But works fine with eclipse.

```
File file = new File("oozie1.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.ClassGen.ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Source source = new StreamSource(file);
JAXBElement<com.ClassGen.COORDINATORAPP> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(source,        com.ClassGen.COORDINATORAPP.class);
com.ClassGen.COORDINATORAPP obj3 = root.getValue();
obj3.getAction(); // This returns a null. But works fine with eclipse. With Eclipse it returns an ACTION object.
```

Any idea on whats going wrong?

Thanks,

Mahalakshmi

Comment: What is obj3 ? here . Are you getting obj3 as null ? or the obj3.getAction ( your method) returns null ?

Comment: Just made an edit to the above code.. Obj3 is root.getValue() - Here it is: class COORDINATORAPP. it doesn't return null.

Comment: Add your `xml` and class `ClassGen`. Are you sure that same jdk is used in both cases?

Comment: Is your classpath correct when you run it from command line? If your classpath isn't correct, then your context classes won't be found and you'll get null references...

Comment: @Ryan,  I use a Manifest file to specify the classpath while building the jar. Manifest file specifies the external jars used in the project but doesn't specify the java library jars.

Comment: @Ilya: When running in the command line, I removed the packages. I have put all the java files and classes and the xml in the same folder I used JDK 1.6.0 in the Eclipse. I checked the java -version in command line.. it aslo says 1.6.0. But I am not sure if it is a JDK or a JRE. How to add JDK to class path using Manifest File in command line?

Comment: You don't use a manifest if you're not using a jar file to execute, but if you want to specify additional classes, you use the -cp or -classpath option to the java command. Mind you, this will not work if you use the -jar option...

Comment: @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan Have you been able to resolve this issue?  I'm stuck at the same place right now

Comment: @ephilip I couldn't resolve it. But I guess its probably due to jdk differences. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes I was. and yes, the JDK was causing the issue; I had developed it using JDK1.7_60 but the deployment machine was using JDK1.8_05

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the file exists. The problem could be, that the file cannot be found.

```
File file = new File("oozie1.xml");
if(file.exists())
{
  // your code
}
```

Comment: No, I checked. The file is actually present. I even read the complete file in the code and checked.